# build.gradle dependencies auto updates itself

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Time to time, android studio will automatically change the values to the latest version which is extremely annoying and breaks my application. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Did a google search and stackoverflow searched but nothing came up.

Comment: I know the IDE will tell you when there is a newer version but updating your `build.gradle` file? I am not sure it goes that far.

Comment: It's the user who updates the version. Android Studio doesn't do that.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for replying. But i am dead sure it does automatically update by itself when i "clean project". I think i would be aware if i am the one who updated the version myself. Hope this questions helps others in the future who faces the same issue with me.

Comment: This is also now happening to me. Were you able to solve it by using variables for version in dependency? if so, can I see what that looks like?

Comment: @PrerakSola this does happen automatically sometime it just did it to me on google play services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

try:

```
playVersion = '8.3.0'
supportVersion = 'support-v4:22.2.1'
designVersion = '22.2.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$playVersion"
compile "com.android.support:$supportVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$designVersion"
```

**Remember** to replace the `'`s with `"`s.

Comment: Android Studio ignores values stored in variables. This is how I prevent the same problem.

Comment: Awesome. This should solve the problem for sure. Thanks @BrandonDyer.

Comment: With me Android Studio did an upgrade anyway (simply replacing the $value with a version number.

Answer (score 1):

**Android Studio doesn't update the dependencies if you specify the version**

Example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

In this case AS will tell you when there is a newer version **without updating them.**

If you the `+` in your dependencies **gradle updates with the latest version** according to the `build.gradle`.
For example:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

It is a good practice to avoid it.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for sharing, but i do understand + leads to unpredictable and unrepeatable results so i did not have it in my gradle at all. It was 8.3.0 --> 8.4.0 automatically whenever i "clean project".

Comment: It is quite strange. Never happen before that AS updates the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with another developer who had checked out my project, and then started getting build errors shortly thereafter.  When I looked, my support library versions had appeared to have been updated as well.

Turns out this was happening after they had added a new Activity via the Android Studio add an activity wizard.  This was automatically updating the build.gradle file to use the latest support library versions, and also adding the 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0' library as well which I wasn't even using.

I'm wondering if something similar is happening to you, as you are indicating it seems to be periodically happening.

Comment: I've been using activity wizard. I am already using suport:design, so I can't comment on that.

Yes, i believe you are experiencing what has happened to me.